# Partial sum formula of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n-1}} + \sqrt{a_n}}$, where $a_n$ forms an arithmetic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been struggling with this series for a while, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Rationalize the denominator, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}} = \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}{x-y}$, and notice that $a_n - a_{n-1}$ is a constant. Telescoping.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they form an arithmetic sequence, there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a_{n}= a_{n-1}+r$ for all $n\geq 2$. I assume $r>0$, otherwise, the answer is trivial (the series diverge to $\infty$).

Then,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}
= \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}{(\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}})(\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}})}
= \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}{a_n-a_{n-1}}
= \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}{r}
$$
(the trick of simplifying a fraction by multiplying numerator and denominator this way is called *rationalization*). Therefore, for every $N\geq 2$,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n}}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}
= \frac{1}{r} \sum_{n=2}^N (\sqrt{a_{n}}-\sqrt{a_{n-1}})
= \frac{1}{r} (\sqrt{a_{N}}-\sqrt{a_{1}})
$$
as we get a telescoping series. Can you conclude?